# Unable to get authentication token

Tags: angular, api, postman, angular-cli

I'm trying to get authentication token by using the below code but am didnt get any. However, I got token in postman.

```
fetchPeople() { 
    //return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/token',data,{ headers: this.headers }); 
    let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/token";
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.set('grant_type', 'password');
urlSearchParams.set('username', 'user');
urlSearchParams.set('password', 'user');
//let body = urlSearchParams.toString();
const data = 'grant_type=password';
return this.http.post( url, data,
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })}  
  )
  };  
}
console.log(data);
```

Did I missed any logical settings. Please guide me to get authentication token. In console am getting

```
grant_type=password&username=user&password=user
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Live Reloading enabled.
POST http://169.38.82.132:94/token 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: Thanks @Vilsad P P, could you please explain in a little bit, please

Comment: sorry, my bad, only saw the application/json, not the contnet-type header

Comment: Can anyone help me to get the authentication token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetchPeople() { 
    //return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/token',data,{ headers: this.headers }); 
    let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/token";    
const data = 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=user';
return this.http.post( url, data,
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })}  
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
})
  };  
}
console.log(data);
```

The http post is returning a observable, so you can subscribe and process your response

Comment: Great ! got authentication token in console area, but with few error messages like in this url - http://sampledemos.online/image/auth.png

Comment: fetchPeople() : Observable<any> { 
    //return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/token',data,{ headers: this.headers }); 
    let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/token";    
const data = 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=user';
return this.http.post( url, data,
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })}  
  ).
  };  
}
console.log(data);
}

fetchPeople() .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
})

change the return type of fetchPeople()  and then subscribe to it

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples

Comment: One doubt @Vilsad PP , am having token in `this.token = Venktoken;  console.log(this.token); ` can you please tell me on how to pass the same in the header section  in authorization field - `{headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': 'bearer '+ this.token,` I tried to pass like above but it is not working, can you help me in this part

Comment: I would suggest you use a token interceptor, there are plenty of sample available and it will be easy to use as well